# How to Call Global Variables From Constructors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a class that looks like this:

```js
class MyClass {

    constructor() {
        this.field = 42;
    }
    
    method() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

I want to define an instance of it as a global variable, so I registered it:

```js
global.MyObject= new MyClass();
```

Which means this will now work:

```js
console.log(MyObject.field); // 42
console.log(MyObject.method()); // Hello world!
```

However, whenever I call that same code from another class it suddenly becomes a lot more random:

```js
class OtherClass {

    constructor() {
        console.log(MyObject.field); // undefined
        console.log(MyObject.method()); // TypeError: MyObject.method is not a function
    }
}
```

Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't. I am not able to find out when it works and when it doesn't, only that it isn't totally random. Called from the same place, the constructor either works or not. Which does not help to isolate the problem.

It seems that when the class's constructor is called from a module that does not have a direct `require('my-class')` it will not work - even when `OtherClass` has that requironment? Even when every other module has that `require`? Which does not make any sense.

I tried it with two modules A and B. If A defines global variables, B can access them just fine even without a `require` - as long as someone else has it.

So... I'm stumped at how this works. Might be a silly JavaScript gimmick, I'm not a native JavaScript developer.

My setup looks like this:

- src/

  - ActualCode (uses functionality that will create `OtherClass`)
- test/

  - mock/

    - MyClass
    - OtherClass (`require('MyClass')`)
  - ActualCodeTest  (`require('ActualCode')`, `require('OtherClass')`

The constructor in `OtherClass` will be able to access `MyClass` when called from `MyClass` and  `OtherClass`, but not from `ActualCode` or `ActualCodeTest`. Even if called in sequence (so the global variable definitively exists).

Which means changing parameters and adding a `require` is out of the question, since the `ActualCode` should never know test code.

The problem seems to be with the Mocha framework. The global variable cannot be accessed inside the "it":

```js
console.log(MyObject.field); // 42

it('test', () => {
    console.log(MyObject.field); // undefined
}
```

If I remove the surrounding code it will (obviously) work.

How do I call global variables from a class's constructor?

Comment: What's `global`?    is this node?, if so to make your code more portable, you might consider using `globalThis` instead.   And then you would do `globalThis.MyObject.field`..  But personally I wouldn't do global vars this way anyway, and use modules instead.

Comment: Don't use globals. But if you really, really want to destroy your program safety and make it hard to reason about, what is `globals`--are you on NodeJS? If so, please tag it as such. If a class constructor relies on a piece of data, why not use a parameter?

Comment: @ggorlen My code is run against (and inside) a complex JavaScript application (that is not mine). To test this code I'm creating mock code. Since the "complex JavaScript application" uses global variables,  my mocks need to do that too. So using a parameter is out of the question, as is anything that will not put the field in `MyObject.field`.

Comment: Providing context is good, thanks, but I doubt it's a coin flip as to whether access works or not. Without a [mcve] it's hard to do more than speculate as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Mocha can't access global variables in its tests. I could not find the
relevant bug for this behavior, but at least a [person with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990025/nodemochaglobal-variables-not-accessible-when-testing-with-mocha).

Since the global variables are only used in the tests, I get to have an easy solution:

```js
global.MyObject= new MyClass();

module.exports.MyObject = MyObject;
```

And this in the test:

```js
before(() => {
    global.MyObject = require('./mock/my-class').MyObject;
});
```

It's probably a good idea to add a TODO so you can revisit this issue every now and then in case the Mocha crew fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code works as expected when you have it all in a single file:

```
$ cat sample.js 
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.field = 42;
    }

    method() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
global.MyObject = new MyClass();

class OtherClass {
    constructor(props) {
        console.log(MyObject.field);
        console.log(MyObject.method());
    }
}

new OtherClass();
$ node sample
42
Hello world!
```

I suspect the confusion comes in the sequence those lines are run when you're loading the modules.  Node's module-loading code will run every line in the sequence they are encountered.

Comment: Don't tell me it's a good idea in JavaScript to put all code in the same file?

Comment: And the definition of the global variables is definitively run before either of the classes, that's easy to check.

Comment: No, it definitely isn't!  But as others have noted it also isn't a great idea to use `global` as a place to store stuff.  My answer is just demonstrating that what you're trying to do works fine in the most basic case.  A single file removes the complexity of module loading, showing that one constructor can access the `global` object.

Comment: ...my question is not if it works in the most basic situation. I KNOW it works. I even laid out the environments where I it does. Doesn't help me with my case where it doesn't.

Comment: I feel for you if you're having to work with legacy code that's using `global`.  If my answer doesn't help identify the issue, feel free to update the question with more details on how the different JS modules are loaded, and I can update mine to try to match.